# Trouble building associative array from xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to build an associative array from XML. Here is what xml looks like (total of about 70 'item' entries):

```
<xmldata>
<source>source</source>
<release>release</release>
 <item>
  <name>Name</name>
  <date>1/1/2015</date>
  <time>10AM</time>
  <value>24</value>
 </item>
 <item>
  <name>Name</name>
  <date>1/1/2015</date>
  <time>10AM</time>
  <value>24</value>
 </item>
etc
...
</xmldata>
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$data = file_get_contents("xml url");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$counter = 1;
$new_array = array();
foreach($xml->children() as $item)
{
  if($counter > 2)
  {
    $temp_array = array('name' => $item->name, 'value' => $item->value);
    array_push($newArray, $temp_array);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to build an associative array that looks like this:

```
$new_array = array(array("name"=>name, "value"=>value),array("name"=>name,  "value"=>value),array("name"=>name, "value"=>value), etc);
```

It's not working. I try to print the array to see if it is formed but I get a list of 0-array, 1-array, etc.

I've also tried `array_merge(), and $new_array[] = $item, and array_push($new_array, array("name"=>name, "value"=>value));`

Is there a preferred way to append associative arrays onto an array? i.e. like `array.append(dict)` in python? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

try like that

```
$data = file_get_contents("xml url");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$counter = 1;
$new_array =[];
foreach($xml->children() as $item)
{
    $new_array[$counter]['name'] = $item->name;
    $new_array[$counter]['value'] = $item->value;
    $counter += 1;              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to add the `name` and the `value` from each `<item>` in the xml to an array, is to first check if `$item->getName()` is "item".

Then you can use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-push.php) to add a new array to the `$new_array`.

For example:

```
$data = file_get_contents('xml url');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$new_array = array();

foreach($xml->children() as $item) {
    if ($item->getName() === "item") {
        array_push(
            $new_array, [
                "name" => $item->name->__toString(),
                "value" => $item->value->__toString()
            ]
        );
    }
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Will result in:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Name' (length=4)
      'value' => string '24' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Name' (length=4)
      'value' => string '24' (length=2)
```